# Interface builder/Objective C problem

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, user-interface, interface-builder

I'm trying to create an application in interface builder, and I'm having a problem. What I want is to create a screen with an image, together with a sectionIndexTitlesForTableView bar.

When the sectionIndexTitlesForTableView bar is touched, I want the image to disappear (and never reappear again), and to jump directly to the selected section of a contact list.

Can anyone give a hint about the best way to have both the bar and the view associated with the image at the same time on screen, and the way to make the image disappear.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Best regards,
Camilo

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what your `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView` does and also what touching the image does, it's not very clear

Comment: I explained in more detail in my answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the image like this

`myImageView.hidden = YES;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's enough (I'm not with my Mac now), because what I want is to have an image in front of the table, like in the first page of a contact's book. 
I want the "cover page" part of the image to hide the table with the contacts initially, but the right part of the image (the one with all the letters - maybe another image) not to hide the bar needed to scroll the table, only to be seen behind it.

Once touched the bar, I want the image (the book cover) to disappear and never be seen again, and the contact's book to open exactly in the contact's page of the touched letter (again, like in the standard iPhone contacts), but the right part of the image (the one behind the scroll bar) to remain on screen during the application execution, and eventualy change (or whatever).

I starter with a view controller, and with the image, but I'm not sure how to put the bar in front of the image without an associated table. Now I'm thinking about starting with the table, an image in front of it, and maybe another image to put behind the scroller bar.

For now, I'm only thinking, for without my mac I cannot try it.

Anyway, thanks for the answer. At least for the "hide the cover page" part, It should work.